# Python from two methods got different result

Tags: python, differential-equations

Every day, I spend time looking inside deeper of 2 different method written in a Python class. 
The first one uses vectors, the second one is a stepper and computes the value each time ... but it is identically here the class.

```
class LeapFrog(Multistep):
    '''
        perform the solution of a SODE using 2 step 
    '''
    solved = False
    um1 = 0.0
    stepper_start = True

    def __init__(self, dydt : Rhs, filename: str=None, save: bool= True ):

        self.save = save
        self.file   = filename
        super().__init__(dydt) 

    def solve(self):
        ''' 
            Perform the leap-frog (mid point scheme)
        '''
        self.time , self.u = self.dydt.createArray()


        # start-up the method
        k1 = self.dydt.f(self.time[0],self.u[0])
        k2 = self.dydt.f(self.time[0]+ self.dt , self.u[0]+ self.dt*k1 )

        self.u[1] = self.u[0] + self.dt/2.*(k1+k2)

        for i in range(1,len(self.time)-1):
            self.u[i+1] = self.u[i-1] + 2. * self.dt * self.dydt.f(self.time[i],self.u[i])

        if self.save:
          return self.time,self.u


        LeapFrog.solved = True 

    @classmethod
    def step(cls ,func , t : np.float , u : np.float , dt ):

       def f(ti,ui):
            return  np.array([function(ti,ui) for function in func])     
       # start-up the method 
       if LeapFrog.stepper_start == True:
           LeapFrog.um1 = u.copy()
           u = rungekutta.RK2.Heun.step(func,t,u,dt)
       LeapFrog.stepper_start = False 
       #yield 

       unext = LeapFrog.um1 + 2. * dt * f(t,u)
       LeapFrog.um1 = u 
       return unext
```

[image: here the difference]

**EDIT** in both case I use dt = 2/100 
Sorry !! I forgot to sayd that the iterative method is called as follow :

```
 dt = 2/100 
   t,u = t0,u0 
   with open('LeapFrog_p1.dat', 'w') as f:
        while True:
            f.write('%10.4f %14.10f \n' %(t, u[0]) )
            u = multistep.LeapFrog.step(func0,t,u,dt)
            t += dt
            if t >= tf:
               break




   lft = np.genfromtxt('LeapFrog_p1.dat',usecols=(0,)) 
   lfu = np.genfromtxt('LeapFrog_p1.dat',usecols=(1,))
```

**EDIT** @Iguananaut thank you for your hint ! t0 =0 tf = 2.0 u0 = np.exp(-5)

Runge Kutta is another class it's stepper is :

```
        @classmethod
        def step(cls,func , t : np.float , u : np.float , dt ):

            def f(ti,ui):
                return  np.array([function(ti,ui) for function in func])     

            k1 = f(t,u)
            k2 = f(t+dt , u + dt*k1)

            unext = u + dt/2.*(k1+k2)       
            return unext
```

> Your code has several other design problems that I'm concerned about, so it's hard to pin down exactly what the problem would belockquote

Could you please tell me which ?? I would like to improve it

Comment: how many iterations are you allowing the iterative method to compute? Does it run until it converges, or only for a fixed number of steps?

Comment: Although it appears to be pretty unambiguous in this case, please be careful about getting your indentation *exactly* the same as what you ran when pasting your code.  You can just paste the code you ran directly in the editor on StackOverflow, highlight the code, and press `Ctrl-K` to indent it.

Comment: What are `t0`, `u0`, `func0`, and `tf`?

Comment: Also where does `rungekutta` come from?  Is that a particular package you're using?

Comment: Your code has several other design problems that I'm concerned about, so it's hard to pin down exactly what the problem would be.